# Why custom control doesn't resize with its children?

Tags: java, javafx, skinning

Consider the following minimal reproducible example:

```java
public class Launcher extends Application {

    public static final double SCENE_SIZE = 500;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setGridLinesVisible(true);
        grid.getColumnConstraints().setAll(
                new ColumnConstraints(USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Priority.NEVER, HPos.LEFT, false),
                new ColumnConstraints(USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Priority.ALWAYS, HPos.LEFT, false)
        );
        grid.getRowConstraints().setAll(
                new RowConstraints(USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Priority.NEVER, VPos.TOP, false),
                new RowConstraints(USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Priority.NEVER, VPos.TOP, false),
                new RowConstraints(USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Priority.NEVER, VPos.TOP, false)
        );

        CustomControl customControl = new CustomControl("Lorem Ipsum ".repeat(10));
        customControl.prefWidthProperty().bind(grid.widthProperty());

        TextFlow textFlow = new TextFlow(new Text("Lorem Ipsum ".repeat(10)));
        textFlow.prefWidthProperty().bind(grid.widthProperty());

        grid.add(new Label("0"), 0, 0);
        grid.add(customControl, 1, 0);
        grid.add(new Label("1"), 0, 1);
        grid.add(textFlow, 1, 1);
        grid.add(new Label("2"), 0, 2);
        grid.add(new Label("..."), 1, 2);

        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, SCENE_SIZE, SCENE_SIZE);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Demo");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(t -> Platform.exit());
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    static class CustomControl extends Control {

        private final StringProperty text = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public CustomControl(String text) { setText(text); }

        public String getText() { return text.get(); }

        public StringProperty textProperty() { return text; }

        public void setText(String text) { this.text.set(text); }

        @Override
        protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() { return new CustomControlSkin(this); }
    }

    static class CustomControlSkin extends SkinBase<CustomControl> {

        TextFlow textFlow;

        public CustomControlSkin(CustomControl control) {
            super(control);

            textFlow = new TextFlow();
            textFlow.getChildren().setAll(new Text(control.getText()));
            control.textProperty().addListener(
                    (obs, old, value) -> textFlow.getChildren().setAll(new Text(control.getText()))
            );

            control.heightProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> System.out.println("control = " + newValue));
            textFlow.heightProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> { System.out.println("textFlow = " + newValue); });

            getChildren().setAll(textFlow);
        }
    }
}
```

Window resize triggers TextFlow word wrapping and therefore TextFlow changes its height. The problem is that it doesn't lead to CustomControl height change, it remains unchanged (notice console output).

At the same time "pure" TextFlow on the next grid row behaves exactly what expect from CustomControl. It changes its height (and GridPane row height as well) back and forth as window resizes.

I thought that any control changes its own height depending on the height of the children automatically (SkinBase contains lots of methods for that), but it seems I was wrong. Simply setting control height in the TextFlow listener won't help, because this way it can be only increased.

**UPDATE:**

Ok, I've found the problem. This happens because TextFlow needs actual width to calculate its preferred height, but SkinBase uses [negative width value](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/782f22a118b71c86b33b37d13e59b308b3cf7f41/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/SkinBase.java#L413). Solution:

```java
control.widthProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    control.setPrefHeight(textFlow.prefHeight(newValue.doubleValue()));
});
```

If there's a better way feel free to share :)

**UPDATE 2:**

Based on the @Slaw advice, this one working as well. Weird thing is that `width` arg value is always `-1`, so we have to get width value from skinnable.

```java
static class CustomControlSkin extends SkinBase<CustomControl> {

    // ...

    @Override
    protected double computePrefHeight(double width, double topInset, double rightInset, double bottomInset,
                                       double leftInset) {
        return textFlow.prefHeight(getSkinnable().getWidth() != 0 ? getSkinnable().getWidth() : -1);
    }

    @Override
    protected double computeMaxHeight(double width, double topInset, double rightInset, double bottomInset,
                                      double leftInset) {
        return computePrefHeight(width, topInset, rightInset, bottomInset, leftInset);
    }
}
```

Comment: When it comes to width and height, override the `computeXXXWidth` and `computeXXXHeight` methods from `SkinBase` as needed. Don't set the dimension properties of the control directly. And override `layoutChildren` if you need a different layout algorithm than provided by the default implementation. Also, if you need to listen to observables from the control then use `registerChangeListener` so that the listeners are automatically removed when the skin is disposed (so long as you remember to call `super.dispose()` if you override that method).

Comment: It would be nice if you would write up the answer as an answer so that you could accept it, assuming somebody else doesn't write a better one.

Comment: Yes, it's general advice. But you weren't using those methods which is why I brought them up. It's also why I wrote a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: @Slaw Thx, again. I've played with those methods all day and nothing seems to work. I still don't understand why Control doesn't call `computePrefHeight()` each time its width changes, it only calls `computeMaxHeight()`, and why width value passed in those methods is always `-1`. But your comment pushed me to try again and I agree that using API that was implemented exactly for uses cases like this one is better than listener hacks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the @Slaw advice, here is one of possible solutions. Weird thing is that `width` arg value is always `-1`, so we have to get width value from skinnable.

```java
static class CustomControlSkin extends SkinBase<CustomControl> {

    // ...

    @Override
    protected double computePrefHeight(double width, double topInset, double rightInset, double bottomInset,
                                       double leftInset) {
        return textFlow.prefHeight(getSkinnable().getWidth() != 0 ? getSkinnable().getWidth() : -1);
    }

    @Override
    protected double computeMaxHeight(double width, double topInset, double rightInset, double bottomInset,
                                      double leftInset) {
        return computePrefHeight(width, topInset, rightInset, bottomInset, leftInset);
    }
}
```

Each time Control width changes it calls `computeMaxHeight()` which simply delegates calculation to the `SkinBase`. Then we just force Control to always use TextFlow pref height.

Comment: The value of the `width` argument is whatever the layout passes in. The layout will (may or may not?) take the content bias of the node into account. If your control's height depends on its width then make sure to override `getContentBias()` and return `Orientation.HORIZONTAL`. See if that works.

Comment: @Slaw It does work. Thank you again! I wish there was detailed documentation about controls customization and layout API. Every time I see methods implementation like `layoutInArea()` my mind blows up :)

Comment: trying to understand implementation details (which typically are not overly well documented) means reading code, reading code, reading code .. there are enough skin implementations to dive into :)